# WPF Binding sub class to Listview

Tags: wpf, listview, bind, subclass

I have this class:

```
public class Car
{
    public struct CarType
    {
        public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
    }

    public CarType Type;
    public string LicenseNumber { get; set; }
    public int Km { get; set; }
}
```

To bind LicenseNumber or Km to my listview, I use:

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Width="140" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LicenseNumber}">
            <GridViewColumn.Header>
                <GridViewColumnHeader Click="GridViewColumnHeader_Click">License Number</GridViewColumnHeader>
            </GridViewColumn.Header>
        </GridViewColumn>
   </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

The command `DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LicenseNumber}"` binds to LicenseNumber property.

But how to bind sub-class. like Type.Manufacturer? Type.Model?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to properties on instances as well (just use the dot notation that you are already familiar with):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Type.Manufacturer}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably never tried.

```
<GridViewColumn Width="140" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type.Manufacturer}">
```

Comment: Actually I tried. It does not add the property under the column. Probably because the binding does not work. This answer is for the guy above too who suggested the same solution.

Comment: Well, do you get a binding error in your Visual Studio output window?

Answer (score 0):

You should using following code:

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Width="140" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type.Manufacturer}">
           ...
```